# Limit number of checkboxes to be selected, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

A simpler version of this question has already been posted, but I'm having some difficulty.

Say I have 5 checkboxes:

- None
- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Pear

The user is allowed to select two checkboxes, but if "None" is chosen, they can only select one.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: It's possible, you should always make an attempt first, and then when you get stuck, ask the question. People are less inclined to help when no effort has been made.

Comment: Please provide an JSFiddle where you have tried to do it.

Comment: You could have started working on the simpler version and tried something here and there and get stuck in some place...

Answer (score 2):

Try to play with this example:

```
var checked = [],
$check = $('.check').change(function() {
    if (this.value == -1 && this.checked) {
        $check.not(this).prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
        checked = [];
    }
    else {
        $check.prop('disabled', false);
        checked.push(this);
        checked = $(checked)
        checked.prop('checked', false).slice(-2).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7Dve/