# Limit number of checkboxes and update string based on their value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338338/772437) which does part of what I want to do, uncheck checkboxes when people go past a certain limit.

Now I want to modify it so that the values of the checkboxes are added to and removed from a string as the checkboxes are checked/unchecked.

My updated code looks like this:

```
var filterURL = '';
var checked = [],
$check = $('.accordion-list input').change(function() {
    checked.push(this);
    checked = $(checked);
    checked.prop('checked', false).slice(-6).prop('checked', true);
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        filterURL += ($(this).val());
    }
    else {
        filterURL = filterURL.replace($(this).val(),'');
    }
    alert(filterURL);
});
```

This works fine until I start to try and uncheck checkboxes – they don't uncheck and the value keeps getting appended to the string.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyssen/3tmx23zc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.checkboxes input').change(function() {
    var filterURL = $('.checkboxes input:checked').map(function(){
       return $(this).val();
    }).get().join('');

    $('#output').html(filterURL);
});
```

Comment: To be honest I would probably get rid of the slash in the `value` attribute and put it in the `join('/')` too, your call though

Comment: That fixes the adding and removing of values to the string, but the unchecking of inputs doesn't work which was part of my original problem. I've updated the Fiddle with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vals = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { vals.push($(this).val()); });
```